# Converting a string to an array of strings (without .split)

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a method that will take a sentence (a String) and convert it into an array of words (Strings) (and it will return this array).  I'm looking for a manual way to do this, without .split or tokenize.

So far, all I have in terms of code is the name of my method

```
public String[] tokenize();
```

After that, I'm at a loss of where to start.  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:  The string is not of fixed length, the input sentence can be anything.

Comment: do you have a string delimiter? Are the strings fixed length?

Comment: how in the world are you going to split the string into arrays without tokenization????

Comment: (1) Identify the places at which you wish to cut your string (2) for each spot where you wish too cut, take substring of the length covering the run to the next cutting spot; save substring in a list (3) continue with the process until the entire string is tokenized.

Answer (score 0):

You probably would want to use java.util.Scanner and construct the scanner with the string

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(string);
sc.useDelimiter(\p{Space});
while(sc.hasNext)
{
  string[i] = sc.next();
}
```

or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Or, use a for loop, check each character, and chop off a substring.